# Round numbers of Image Collection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, image, decimal-points, round-function

I have an image collection filtered data

How can I compute sum reducer with two decimal places of my total image.

```
var imagess = chirps
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2022-02-01', '2022-02-10'));
print(imagess)  

var total = imagess.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum())
print(total);
```

I am applying the following but it does not seem to work

```
var total = imagess.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum())
  .multiply(100).round().divide(100);  // Round to two decimal points

print(total);
```

Comment: Why do you say it does not seem to work? I ran your code and it shows the expected output.

Comment: I also got the same  expected output.